# PHP DOMDocument not removing all element

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to remove all `script` element and here the code

```
<?php
$pageFile = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script src="aa"></script>
<script src="bb"></script>
<script src="cc"></script>
<div>aaa</div>
</body></html>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($pageFile);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $item) {
  $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
}
$pageFile = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $pageFile;
```

but there still 1 `script` element exist. You can try it online [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51088a320942f8d2cae9034d5a78e9e99c6c70fc)

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<script src="bb"></script><div>aaa</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DOMNodeList` returned by `$dom->getElementsByTagName` is "live". So when you remove a script, it's removed from the node list, and all the elements of the list shift their indexes down. Then the `for` loop goes to the next index, and it ends up skipping every other element.

Convert the node list to an array first.

```
foreach (iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('script')) as $item) {
  $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify, and even delete, nodes from a DOMNodeList if you iterate backwards:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#83390
use:

```
<?php
$pageFile = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script src="aa"></script>
<script src="bb"></script>
<script src="cc"></script>
<div>aaa</div>
</body></html>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($pageFile);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
for ($i = $elements->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
  $elem = $elements->item($i);
  $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem);
}
$pageFile = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $pageFile;
```